# set iOS background image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad

I am making an application that need to set the device background image within code but I can't figure this out.

I've tried searching all the web but had no luck finding an answer for this.

**It will be great if you can help me doing this**

Comment: apple  doesn't allow you to change the device bgimage from inside an app, sow even if you make the app, you can't putt it on the appstore

Comment: so must be with jail breaking :(
any code to help doing it with jailbreak ?

Comment: You can't do this via code this is impossible

Comment: Do you mean setting the background of the actual device? Like the home screen? Or Background within an iPhone App?

Answer (score 3):

It's impossible without jailbreaking.

Comment: This should be comment not answer

Comment: so must be with jail breaking :(
any code to help doing it with jailbreak ?